# Error con json discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

cuando quiero escribir en el chat de discord para subir de nivel, aqui esta el codigo

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Programacion\python\Otras cosas\bot discord')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
       users = json.load(f)
   
   await update_data(users, member)

   #Code
   
   with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(users, f)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
       users = json.load(f)

   await update_data(users, message.author)
   await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
   await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

   #Code
   
   with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
   if not user.id in users:
       users[user.id] = {}
       users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
       users[user.id]['level'] = 1
async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
   users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
   experience = users[user.id]['experience']
   lvl_start = users[users.id]['level']
   lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
   
   if lvl_start < lvl_end:
       await bot.send_message(channel, '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
       users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end
```

Comment: Cual es el json?

Comment: El problema ocurre cuando intentas cargar un json que no tiene un formato json válido, para encontrar el error debes proporcionar el contenido de los archivos o verificar su estructura con un validador de json. Adicionalmente debes tener cuidado con bloquear el event loop con acciones síncronas como `open(...)`, utiliza una versión asíncrona con `aiofile` o un paquete similar.